# How to pass angular component template as stringified html to backend developer

Tags: html, angular

I created an angular component and now i want to pass the components html as a post method to angular http

I tried converting to html using stringy but not able to add css for the same html page.I need help with css part .Also i need to convert angular component to html content

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.